# How can I fix the documentation formatting in Qt Assistant?

Tags: qt

I finally decided to build Qt from source, so I cloned Qt5 from the git repository and built everything. So far everything looks pretty good, except that the documentation appears different from before.

Here is a screenshot of what I am used to (see the documentation pane on the right):

[image]

But here is what Qt Assistant looks like now:

[image]

Notice how the "Contents" area isn't pulled to the right, all the links are blue, and some of the styling appears off.

What is wrong? Did I not compile `assistant` properly, or did Qt change the way they format their documentation?